# Pythonic way to 'divide' a list into lists

Tags: python

```
a = [1,2,'asd',2,22,'gwrg',3,222,'egeg',4,2222,'qwqe']
```

I want to make lists from this

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4]
a2 = [2,22,222,2222]
a3 = ['asd','gwrg','egeg','qwqe']
```

I can do it using for-loop, collecting elements with index modulo 3, but is there more pythonic way to do it? I mean, not using for-loop?

Comment: What is criterion you considered? I think string elements are in a3, but what is difference between a1 and a2?

Comment: `a[::3]`, `a[1::3]` and `a[2::3]`

Comment: @Nick Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: For loops **are** pythonic.

Comment: For loops *are perfectly pythonic*